# Hypergeometric Variance

Tags: statistics, hypergeometric-function

I have a question about finding the variance quickly which came from my textbook.
Suppose there are 6 men and 4 women with 3 promotion positions available. The director decides to select 3 randomly. Let X denote the number of men hired. Find the standard deviation of X, hence we need to find the variance. The solution book finds the mean using its formula but then the solution book said that the same logic can be solved to find $E(X ^2)$ which is then used to find the variance.

I don't understand what the logic they used was, can someone explain it to me? I thought of making a table where the $X$ values are squared but that requires 4 hypergeometric calculations.

Edit: sorry my question wasn't clear before

Comment: Find the variance of what?

Comment: Please edit your post to ask a clear and complete question.  I'm guessing you meant to define a variable that counts the number of promoted men (or maybe women), and that we are to assume the selection is uniformly random amongst the $10$ candidates, but why make your readers guess?

Comment: Trusting that my guess is more or less correct...it is easy to get the exact distribution here, so you can just compute the variance directly from the definition.

Comment: @lulu Hope my edit is provides a clear understanding of what the question is about. But based on your comment, what do you mean by 'compute'? Do you perhaps mean using r code?

Comment: There are only $4$ possible values $X$ can take!  You can do it by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Is there no shortcut for it then? I'm asking this since I'm concerned with my time management in exams situation.

Comment: I can't imagine anything shorter than the direct computation.

Comment: I guess you could use indicator values...letting $M_i$ be the indicator for the $i^{th}$ man, you want $E[(M_1+\cdots +M_6)^2]$ which can be broken up into terms like $E[M_1^2]=E[M_1]$ and $E[M_1\times M_2]$.  Not sure this is any faster though.

Comment: Having reviewed both methods, I'd say the indicator variable approach was indeed faster, though it's less intuitive and it has fewer obvious checks.  I prefer the direct method...always use the exact distribution if it is available...but there's nothing wrong with the other approach.